# Python: Circular regression to determine center and radius

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I followed [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219235331/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55239.html) to calculate for center and radius given three points (x, y) coordinates. I have written the following python code, but the h and k values I got are still matrices, so I am wondering how to calculate for these two values based on that tutorial:

```
import numpy as np
from math import *

last_point = (2, -4)
second_last_point = (6, -2)
third_last_point = (5, 5)

points = []
points.append(last_point)
points.append(second_last_point)
points.append(third_last_point)


h_numerator = []
h_denominator = []

k_numerator = []

for index in range(len(points)):
    current_point = points[index]

    h_denominator.append([current_point[0], current_point[1], 1])
    h_numerator.append([current_point[0] ** 2 + current_point[1] ** 2, current_point[1], 1])

    k_numerator.append([current_point[0], current_point[0] ** 2 + current_point[1] ** 2, 1])



h_numeratorMatrix = np.matrix(np.array(h_numerator))
denominatorMatrix = np.matrix(np.array(h_denominator))

k_numeratorMatrix = np.matrix(np.array(k_numerator))


h = h_numeratorMatrix / (2. * denominatorMatrix)
k = k_numeratorMatrix / (2. * denominatorMatrix)

print 'h=', h
print 'k=', k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed one small detail from tutorial:

> The simplest forms of 
>   these involve **determinants**

And you're trying to divide matrices (`h = h_numeratorMatrix / (2. * denominatorMatrix)`)
So, correct code to calculate `h` and `k` should be as follows:

```python
h = np.linalg.det(h_numeratorMatrix) / (2. * np.linalg.det(denominatorMatrix))
k = np.linalg.det(k_numeratorMatrix) / (2. * np.linalg.det(denominatorMatrix))
```

P.S.
*This part of code*

```python
for index in range(len(points)):
    current_point = points[index]
```

*could be changed to:*

```python
for current_point in points:
    ...
```